# pattern matching functions with same name in different modules

Tags: elixir

I wanted to extend the type of flash messages, but I get errors when I do the following:

```
defmodule Backend.AuthView do
  use Backend.Web, :view

  def flash(message, :auth_info) do
    ...
  end
  def flash(message, :auth_notice) do
   ... 
  end
end
```

and import this into another module:

```
defmodule Backend.LayoutView do
  use Backend.Web, :view
  import Backend.AuthView

  def flashes(conn) do
    markup safe: true do
      messages = Enum.reduce [:notice, :error], [], fn(which, acc) ->
        case get_flash(conn, which) do
          nil -> acc
          _ -> acc ++ [{ which, get_flash(conn, which)}]
        end
      end
      if messages != [] do
        Enum.map messages, fn({which, message}) ->
          flash message, which
        end
      end
    end
  end
  def flash(message, :info) do
    ...
  end
  def flash(message, :notice) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there a possibility to make something like this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the import to an alias, and implement a fallback function, something like this

```
defmodule Backend.LayoutView do
  use Backend.Web, :view
  alias Backend.AuthView

  def flash(message, :info) do
    ...
  end

  def flash(message, :notice) do
    ...
  end

  def flash(message, other) when is_atom(other) do
    AuthView.flash(message, other)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was hoping I'd only need to add one line to LayoutView, but this is perfectly acceptable. Thanks.